# React Router 4: Pass route props to layout component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass the route props to a layout component which performs initial API requests with the route props, the problem is that these route props are only passed to the child routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <AppLayout> // This AppLayout performs API requests
                    // with the :route param in the child routes.
            <Route path="/some/:route" component={SomeComponent} />
            <Route path="/some/other/:route" component={OtherComponent} />
        </AppLayout>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Obviously, once the user hits the `/some/:route` route, the layout would have been already rendered. I tried doing something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/some/:route" render={(props) =>
        (<AppLayout {...props}><SomeComponent /></AppLayout>)} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

This works but the AppLayout would be unmounted and remounted every time I go to another route using the same layout.

With react-router 3, I could do something like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={AppLayout}>
        <Route path="/some/:route" component={SomeComponent} />
        <Route path="/some/other/:route" component={OtherComponent} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

And the route props would be available on the AppLayout component.

Is there a way of actually achieving this with react-router 4?

Comment: definitely check out react-router's [`matchPath`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to nest routes you should do something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={props => <AppLayout {...this.props} />} />
        <Route exact path="/some/:route" component={AppLayout} />
        <Route exact path="/some/other/:route" component={AppLayout}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Notice how I am passing the router props to `AppLayout` and using the `AppLayout` component as a handler for both the routes. Now inside the `AppLayout` component you'll have to mention these routes again with their respective components, like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/some/:route" render={props => <SomeComponent {...this.props} />} />
  <Route exact path="/some/other/:route" render={props => <OtherComponent {...this.props} />} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, although it seems rather counterproductive, specially since this was possible before with a much simpler approach.

Comment: Yes indeed it is counterproductive. Handling routes with react router 3 was way more simpler and straightforward.